# libssh2 Undefined reference

Tags: linux, openssl, fedora, libssh2

I'm using a pc with fedora29 installed trying to compile using libssh2-1.9.0 using openssl-1.1.1. It used to be able to compile fine, but recently when trying to compile again, I'm getting a giant list of undefined reference errors. Here is are 2 sample snippets:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ~/libssh2/libssh2.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x620a): more undefined references to `EVP_DigestUpdate' follow
/usr/bin/ld: ~/libssh2/libssh2.a(kex.o): in function `kex_method_diffie_hellman_group_exchange_sha256_key_exchange':
kex.c:(.text+0x634c): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6356): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x64cf): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x64e6): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x64f3): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x652c): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6543): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6565): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x657f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6601): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x671f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6736): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
/usr/bin/ld: kex.c:(.text+0x6743): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
```

... and more

```
/usr/bin/ld: ~/libssh2/libssh2.a(mac.o): in function `mac_method_hmac_sha1_hash':
mac.c:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x23d): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x24a): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x264): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/libssh2/libssh2.a(mac.o): in function `mac_method_hmac_sha2_512_hash':
mac.c:(.text+0x2fa): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x302): undefined reference to `EVP_sha512'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x31d): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x33a): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x35c): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: ~/libssh2/libssh2.a(mac.o): in function `mac_method_hmac_sha2_256_hash':
mac.c:(.text+0x3ba): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x3ed): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x414): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x41c): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
/usr/bin/ld: mac.c:(.text+0x443): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
```

I tried rebuilding the libssh2 source files and even tried on a different pc (vm) with a fresh install of everything and it also gives me errors and it's slowly driving me insane. Does anyone know of a solution to this?